# program works only when an integer is declared

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was actually trying some C programming code and I came up with this program, which for some reason is working only when an integer is declared and is given some value.

The code below works perfectly

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{


    FILE *file = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo","r");
    char *line;
    int count = 0;
    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(file," %[^\n]",line)!=-1)
        {
            printf("\n%s",line);
        }
        printf("\n\n\t* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFile Does not Exist\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this does not work , (I mean, when I run this I get an infinite loop of (null) values.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo","r");
    char *line;

    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(file," %[^\n]",line)!=-1)
        {
            printf("\n%s",line);
        }
        printf("\n\n\t* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFile Does not Exist\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc compiler

> gcc -v
>
> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
>   --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Can anyone explain what is happening here, I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: "Does not work" means...?

Comment: i am getting a infinite loop of (null) s.

Comment: You´re accessing an unallocated pointer. Behaviour undefined. Besides that, there is no fclose. And...

Comment: @deviantfan : but The first one works perfectly, It does not work only when I remove the integer declaration.

Comment: No, it is not perfect at all. If it works (sometimes), it is only luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *line;
```

should be something like

```
char line[1024];
```

And add a fclose.

edit because of comment:
If you want the first definition and malloc/free:

```
char *line;
line = malloc(1024);
...
free(line);
```

Comment: thanks, Using an array works , but is it possible to acheive the same using pointers ? If yes, I would like to know how.

Comment: The name of an array variable is actually a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Basically, you are passing a pointer to fscanf. If you want more "pointerness", use malloc/free to allocate the 1024 bytes by yourself

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo : Ok, I mean, if we use an array with a fixed size, what if the size of the line is much higher than the size we provided, if we use big array size it won't be efficient isn't it.

Comment: As you don´t know the line size before reading, you would have to get a bigger array once you know the current is not sufficient. Somewhat more complex, as you have to do the reading yourself (instead of fscanf) and handle the whole memory stuff also.

Comment: In those situations you either read in chunks if possible (so that you keep the buffer and memory footprint small) or you allocate on the heap with `malloc`/global.

Comment: @cyberPheonix here's some discussion of the buffer overflow problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating memory for the `line` buffer, which in you case is only an **invalid pointer**.

In the first case, you were (un)lucky, since the pointer was pointing to a writable area (specifically, you were overwriting the memory area in which `count` was located), but in the second case, a segmentation error is raised.

Replace:

```
char *line; // Pointer to... somewhere?
```

with:

```
char line[4096];
```

or any other suitable buffer size. If you need a buffer that won't fit in the stack, then declare it as global variable (strongly discouraged, unless your application is really small or you know what you are doing) or allocate it on the heap, with:

```
char *line = malloc(4096 * 1024);
```

and remember to call `free(line)` when the buffer is not needed anymore (e.g. before terminating the program).

Answer (score 1):

fscanf writes to a buffer pointed to by `char *line;`, but line is never set to point anywhere useful. Presumably adding the extra int causes memory layout to be a little different, so it breaks in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, on Linux at least, you can use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

```
int main() {
  FILE *file = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo","r");
  char *line=NULL;
  size_t linesiz= 0;
  ssize_t linelen= -1;
  if (file == NULL) { perror("/proc/cpuinfo"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
  while ((linelen=getline(&line,&linesiz))>=0) 
    fputs(line,stdout);
  free(line), line=NULL;
  fclose(file);
}
```

However, in practice, we all know that  `/proc/cpuinfo` contain a few long lines (for `flags` notably), but probably the longest line is less than e.g. 512 bytes (on my i3770K with a Linux 3.13 kernel, it has 483 bytes). Knowing that (which is not exactly guaranteed, but is true today, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) you could simply code with [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)

```
char linebuf[512];
do {
  if (fgets(linebuf,sizeof(linebuf),file)==0) break;
  fputs(linebuf, stdout);
} while(!feof(linebuf));
```

Beware that [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) should be used after (not before) some `<stdio.h>` input operation (here `fgets`).

PS. Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and to use the debugger (`gdb`).